# Excel - Sum contents between headers if a string is found

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

[image: Snapshot]

I'm trying to do the following: if it finds a letter "A" in the 3rd column, sum all the values of the 2nd column (that are in the same line as the "A"), but, between the headers is a single range.

I've tried using arrays and other type of functions, but I'm not getting anywhere..

The tricky part is that the sum must restart when it finds a new header.
There are no gaps between headers.

Thanks everyone!

PS. Actually, there aren't any 'blocks' without an "A", like the one you can see below the 2nd header. I've already filtered and deleted those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try entering this in cell D2 and fill down:

```
=IF(LEN(C3)<>1,SUMIF($C$2:C2,"A",$B$2:B2)-SUM($D$1:D1),"")
```

... but if you have many rows it would be preferable to fill simple SUMIF formulas using code. One way to do this is to press `Alt+F11` to access the VB code window, then enter in the immediate window this line and press enter:

```
[E1:E13]=[IF(LEN(OFFSET(C1:C13,1,0))<>1,"=SUMIF(C"&LOOKUP(ROW(C1:C13),ROW(C1:C13)/(C1:C13="H3"))+1&":C"&ROW(C1:C13)&",""A"",B"&LOOKUP(ROW(C1:C13),ROW(C1:C13)/(C1:C13="H3"))+1&":B"&ROW(C1:C13)&")","")]
```

This enters these three formulas in the cells shown and leaves the remaining cells blank.

```
E4  =SUMIF(C2:C4,"A",B2:B4)
E9  =SUMIF(C6:C9,"A",B6:B9)
E13 =SUMIF(C11:C13,"A",B11:B13)
```

Comment: + 1 You never seem to stop surprising me with your formula skills! Good Job!

Comment: I'm impressed... first one is a smart trick and I didn't even know you could use the second one (+2 if I could)

Comment: +1 you remind me somewhat of Barry when it comes to formulae ... and that is something

Comment: Thanks, many of these techniques have been picked up over the years via the online community so I owe a debt of gratitude to many others. Something I recently discovered - but may be known to many others already - is that you can use the VBE Watch window to debug formulas without any code running. So in the case above you can add the `[IF(...)]` formula as a Watch with context (All Procedures) (All Modules) and it will return all elements in the array and data types. Evaluating functions in code this way provides a functional programming aspect to VBA with minimum coding needed.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for sharing your expertise lori_m! I'm very grateful!